# Iterating through a data with a combination of arrays and objects

Tags: javascript

I have to iterate through a data(result from a server) where the result is a mixture of arrays and objects. The parent element is also not confirmed out of two.

I want to write a generic code which will iterate through the result to get the values by identifying the medium.

I hope I'm not asking stupid question, but I couldn't find any definite answer.

EDIT: 
The result from the server can either be an Object containing arrays and child objects. 
Or 
An array containing objects and child arrays.
Its unknown to the user and therefore we will need to implement a generic code.

I think we will need to check the result first for array or object.But I am not sure how to go after that.

Comment: can you post the sample (result from a server)

Comment: Keep in mind that an Array is an Object too.  It's just a special type of Object (essentially a sub-class of Object with extra powers).

Comment: @jfriend00: I understand that but how can I take advantage of this? I added more info to my question also.

Comment: Post a sample of ur different data responses

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how do I know if an entry is an object or an array?" the answer is: `Array.isArray` can tell you:

```
if (Array.isArray(x)) {
    // x is an array
} else {
    // x is not an array
}
```

It wasn't defined until ES5 (~2009), so it's not provided by obsolete JavaScript engines like the one in IE8, but it can be shimmed/polyfilled (MDN had one [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#Polyfill)).

Comment: Array.isArray will recognize if the entry is an array and we will loop using for. Else we will be using for..in. How will we proceed using checks for child objects and arrays? I added more info in my question too.